# Replacing the entire div on hover and switch back on hover out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I have a table and i want to change a div to another div on hover and on hover out i want to change to what was before.

my table

```
<table id="table2">
<body>
  <tr>
     <td>
        <div id="com.zynga.wwf2.free" class="redips-drag orange" style="border-style: solid; cursor: move; background-image: url(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/mm9kB_B7UTEMuG2t914nmu2pox-G5a64GlajDaUdf7M5LfKBeYpBbeouyRVgsBATLSA=w300); background-size: 100px 100px; background-repeat: no-repeat;  width: 100px;
           height: 100px;"></div>
     </td>
  </tr>
</body>
</table>
```

now i want to change the div on hover to this:

```
<div><span>clicks:123</span><br><span>money:7890</span></div>
```

and on hoverout to return to before.

i try this:

```
        var temp_html;
    $("#table2 tr").find('div').hover(function(){
          var temp_html = $(this).clone().wrap('<div>').parent().html();

        $(this).replaceWith("<div><span>clicks:123</span><br><span>money:7890</span></div>");

        }, function() {
       $(this).replaceWith(temp_html);
    });
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide us a little fiddle ? :)

Comment: There you go: https://jsfiddle.net/xvo5ygzp/ (not working version)

Answer (score 3):

Try having both of these divs inside the table and toggle their visibility:

HTML

```
<td id="cell">
  <div id="one"></div>
  <div id="two" class="hidden"></div>
</td>
```

CSS

```
.hidden { display:none }
```

jQuery

```
$('#cell').on('mouseenter', function() {
   var that = $(this);
   that.find('#one').addClass('hidden');
   that.find('#two').removeClass('hidden');
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
   var that = $(this);
   that.find('#one').removeClass('hidden');
   that.find('#two').addClass('hidden');
})
```

**BETTER SOLUTION**

---

Just toggle the class of the hovered element and let CSS take care of the rest!

HTML

```
<td id="cell" class="visibleOne">
  <div id="one"></div>
  <div id="two"></div>
</td>
```

CSS

```
#cell.visibleTwo #one { display:none }
#cell.visibleOne #two { display:none }
```

jQuery

```
$('#cell').on('mouseenter', function() {
   $(this).removeClass('visibleOne').addClass('visibleTwo');
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
   $(this).removeClass('visibleTwo').addClass('visibleOne');
})
```

Comment: But OP needs hover event

Comment: Can bring unexpected behaviour if div two has a height inferior to div one

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS only with `:hover` pseudo class:

```
td .redips-drag + div, td:hover .redips-drag {
    display: none;
}
td:hover .redips-drag + div {
    display: block;
    min-height: 100px; /* set min-height to the biggest height between both elements to swap */
}
```

### DEMO